# Reinforcement Learning on quantum circuit

Tags: neural-networks, python, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

I am trying to teach an agent to make any random 1-qubit state reach uniform superposition. So basically, the full circuit will be `State -> measurement -> new_state (|0> if 0, |1> if 1) -> Hadamard gate`. It just needs to perform `2 actions`. That's all. So it's more of an RL problem rather than QC.

I am using reinforcement learning to train the model but it doesn't seem to learn anything. The reward keeps on decreasing and even after 3 million episodes, the agent doesn't seem to converge anywhere. This is how I am training:

```
def get_exploration_rate(self, time_step):
        return self.epsilon_min + (self.epsilon - self.epsilon_min)*\
               math.exp(1.*time_step*self.epsilon_decay)

def act(self, data,t): #state
        rate = self.get_exploration_rate(t)
        if random.random() < rate:
            options = self.model.predict(data) #state
            options = np.squeeze(options)
            action =  random.randrange(self.action_size)
        else:
            options = self.model.predict(data) #state
            options = np.squeeze(options)
            action = options.argmax()
        return action, options, rate

def train(self):

        batch_size = 200
        t = 0                   #increment
        states, prob_actions, dlogps, drs, proj_data, reward_data =[], [], [], [], [], []
        tr_x, tr_y = [],[]
        avg_reward = []
        reward_sum = 0
        ep_number = 0
        prev_state = None
        first_step = True
        new_state = self.value
        data_inp = self.data

        while ep_number<3000000:
            prev_data = data_inp
            prev_state = new_state
            states.append(new_state)
            action, probs, rate = self.act(data_inp,t)
            prob_actions.append(probs)
            y = np.zeros([self.action_size])
            y[action] = 1
            new_state = eval(command[action])
            proj = projection(new_state, self.final_state)
            data_inp = [proj,action]
            data_inp = np.reshape(data_inp,(1,1,len(data_inp)))
            tr_x.append(data_inp)
            if(t==0):
                rw = reward(proj,0)
                drs.append(rw)
                reward_sum+=rw

            elif(t<4):
                rw = reward(new_state, self.final_state)
                drs.append(rw)
                print("present reward: ", rw)
                reward_sum+=rw
            elif(t==4):
                if not np.allclose(new_state, self.final_state):
                    rw = -1
                    drs.append(rw)
                    reward_sum+=rw
                else:
                    rw = 1
                    drs.append(rw)
                    reward_sum+=rw

            print("reward till now: ",reward_sum)
            dlogps.append(np.array(y).astype('float32') * probs)
            print("dlogps before time step: ", len(dlogps))
            print("time step: ",t)
            del(probs, action)
            t+=1
            if(t==5 or np.allclose(new_state,self.final_state)):                         #### Done State
                ep_number+=1
                ep_x = np.vstack(tr_x) #states
                ep_dlogp = np.vstack(dlogps)
                ep_reward = np.vstack(drs)
                disc_rw = discounted_reward(ep_reward,self.gamma)
                disc_rw = disc_rw.astype('float32')
                disc_rw -= np.mean(disc_rw)
                disc_rw /= np.std(disc_rw)

                tr_y_len = len(ep_dlogp)
                ep_dlogp*=disc_rw
                if ep_number % batch_size == 0:
                  input_tr_y = prob_actions - self.learning_rate * ep_dlogp
                    input_tr_y = np.reshape(input_tr_y, (tr_y_len,1,6))

                    self.model.train_on_batch(ep_x, input_tr_y)
                    tr_x, dlogps, drs, states, prob_actions, reward_data = [],[],[],[],[],[]
                env = Environment()
                new_state = env.reset()
                proj = projection(state, self.final_state)
                data_inp = [proj,5]
                data_inp = np.reshape(data_inp,(1,1,len(data_inp)))
                print("State after resetting: ", new_state)
                t=0
```

I have tried various things like changing the inputs, reward function, even added `exploration rate`. I have assigned max time step as `5` even though it should complete in just `2`.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: does it work on other gym environments?

Comment: I have used the vanilla policy gradient, which is also similar to Karpathy's implementation for pong. So I guess it'll work for gym.

Comment: i strongly recommend you try your algorithm on several gym environments (pong, pendulum, some atari games) to make sure your implementation is absolutely bug-free.

Comment: Well, the thing is, the gym environment takes care of a lot of values, like the reward, episode, done state. I have to do all of this from scratch. So it's not going to be a good comparison. The only thing I'll use is the policy gradient, which is very similar to what people have used.